# sed replace after matching character

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed

I have to change a properties file containing the property:

```
ro.product.firmware=0.0.1
```

with a new value that is coming from a function called in a different section of my bash script. I cannot get the regex to work properly. For this particular case I need the value to be changed from 0.0.1 to $1 but the value will not always be 0.0.1. The regex I currently have  is:

```
sed -i 's/^(ro\.product\.firmware).*$/(ro\.product\.firmware="$1")'
```

Comment: What regex did you try?

Comment: sed -i 's/^(ro\.product\.firmware).*$/(ro\.product\.firmware="$1")'

Comment: Edit your question and include this regex in it. And please read the guidelines for framing a better question, lest your question will be downvoted by other users.

Comment: my apologies, this is my first experience using a professional forum.

Comment: It's okay. However, it would be good to read atleast the formatting guidelines here http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help so that you format your questions better the next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for your case:

```
sed -ri 's/^(ro\.product\.firmware\=)(.*)$/\1'"$1"'/g' file.txt
```

Here,

```
-r ==> for using extended regex
\1 ==> for the first captured group
```

Comment: This is very close except it gives me "$1" instead of the value of the variable

Comment: Okay. It has been edited. Now it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I greatly appreciate the answer. `sed -ri 's/^(ro\.product\.firmware\=)(.*)$/\1'"$1"'/g'` was what I needed in order to print the variable

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

#some logic

export value=$(some_function)
#note the export

#more code

perl -ie 's/^ro\.product\.firmware.*$/ro.product.firmware=$ENV{value};'

#yada yada yada
```